# Why does nsca-ng-server require icinga on nagios server?

Tags: apt, server, nagios3

This is my first question on this forum, so please correct me if necessary.

We have a number of monitoring servers running ubuntu 16.04,18.04 and nagios and I want to give nsca-ng a try for passive checks. It should be completely compatable with nagios, however when I try installing nsca-ng-server, apt wants to install icinga-common and icinga-core as dependencies.
Now I've read about Icinga and it is interesting, but for now not an option to simply replace nagios with icinga. I also don't see why this dependency is there at all since it is a standalone service.
Anyone have a solution to install nsca-ng without pulling in icinga (short of compiling from source) ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: I installed without the icinga dependencies:

```
apt install nsca-ng-server icinga-common- icinga-core-
```

This works fine. It looks like this line in the configuration file

```
command_file= "/var/lib/icinga/rw/icinga.cmd"
```

Is the reason to depend on icinga. That directory will not exist without icinga. Replacing this line with

```
command_file= "/var/lib/nagios3/rw/nagios.cmd"
```

works just fine for me. In my opinion it is a bit lazy of the package maintainers to just pull in icinga as a dependency. But that's off topic.